# Making a new Object in java

Tags: java

What is the difference between this code:

```
    Table table = new Table();
```

and this code:

```
    Table table;

public TableExample(){
    table = new Table();
}
```

Comment: Did you search before asking?

Comment: I did search but I can't seem to understand it at all.

Comment: Then asking the same question that has been asked many many times before, without showing what the fruits of your labors in your question and without asking a more specific question, is not likely going to bring anything new that you will understand.